why is there weird shadows when I separate a model into 2 meshes? and is there a way to fix it?
there these weird shadows show up when I separate a model into 2 meshes,and I don't know how to get rid of them.
I use blender 4.1 if you wanna know, and the model's material has no normals
edit: I just checked that the material has normals node, it just that it doesn't have any other node connected to it.
model after I separate it.

model before I separate it.


the original model is an fbx, I imported it with "Custom Normals", "Custom Properties", "Import Enums As Strings", and "Image Search" being checked. also on the third image, the material has the normals node, probably due to importing the model with custom normals.


What exactly is the part you separated?

the arm, as you can see in the images

Have you done any research, do these answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53749/normals-changed-after-separating-object-in-2-pieces https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65172/fixing-normals-after-separating-mesh-into-new-objects

@Duarte Farrajota Ramos not really, I guess I'll try to figure it out, thanks for the help!

Since the torso and arms are now separate meshes and are not connected, there will be no smooth shading across them. Having the edges split between objects is producing the split normals that you observed.
More information on shading an object smooth or flat can be found here.

Add a "Data Transfer" modifier, and transfer Face Corner Dat → Custom Normals from the original, whole mesh. You can then apply the modifier if you don't want to keep the original mesh. You could even separate the mesh further after that.

